# How to parse Javasript object to an array of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object of data and need a simpe js method to parse that object to a format supported by [quill](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#setcontents) text editor (replace placeholders with their links).

What I have:

```
const data = {
      text: 'Hello this is $link1$ and here is $link2$ and now finally $link3$ cool.',
      links: {
        $link3$: ['link 3', 'https://www.link3.com'],
        $link1$: ['link 1', 'https://www.link1.com'],
        $link2$: ['link 2', 'https://www.link2.com']
      }
};
```

Need a simple javascript/typescript function to which I pass object of `data` and returns this:

What I need:

```
[
 { insert: 'Hello this is ' },
 {
   insert: 'link 1',
   attributes: { link: 'https://www.link1.com' }
 },
 { insert: ' and here is' },
 {
   insert: 'link 2',
   attributes: { link: 'https://www.link2.com' }
 },
 { insert: ' and now finally' },
 {
   insert: 'link 3',
   attributes: { link: 'https://www.link3.com' }
 },
 { insert: ' cool.' },
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Hi @m-yassen. Do you mind explaining why you need to produce such an array? If you intention is to simply replace all the $link$ with their values, there might be a much simpler solution for you.

Comment: I think this question is at least somewhat understandable and doesn't need to be closed, but I would recommend that @MYaseen edit the text to be more explicit about what the question entails and then submit for reopening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is TypeScript it's helpful to define interfaces for the input and output types.  From your example I'm going to guess the following, but you can obviously change them to fit your use case:

UPDATE: apparently the `links` property in `Data` should be optional, so I'll change it to reflect that.

```
interface Data {
    text: string;
    links?: { [k: string]: [string, string] | undefined }
}

interface ParsedData {
    insert: string;
    attributes?: { link: string }
}
```

And now we want to define a `parse()` function that takes an argument of type `Data` and produces a result of type `ParsedData[]`.  Here's one possible way to do it:

```
const parse = (d: Data): ParsedData[] => d.text.
    split(/(\$\w+\$)/).
    map(s => ({ s: s, l: d.links?.[s] })).
    map(({ s, l }) => l ? { insert: l[0], attributes: { link: l[1] } } : { insert: s });
```

What I've done here is split the `text` string into chunks separated by matches of the regular expression `/(\$\w+\$)/`.  That expression specifies a piece of text that starts and dollar sign `$` followed by "word" characters (letters, numbers, and underscore) and then ends with another dollar sign.  Again, if this doesn't exactly match your use case you can likely tweak the regular expression to do so.

Now we have an array of strings to be processed.  Essentially the next two lines map each string to an object.  If the string is a key of the `links` property of the data, it looks up the property (`d.links?.[s]` is using `s` as a property key in the `d.links` object; if `d.links?.[s]` is `undefined` it means `s` is not present as a key.  Note that the `?.` notation is [optional chaining](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) and takes care of the possibility that `d.links` might itself be missing) and formats it as an `insert`/`attributes` object.  Otherwise it just takes the string as the `insert` property with no `attributes`.

Here's the output for your example code:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse(data)));
/* [
    {"insert":"Hello this is "},
    {"insert":"link 1","attributes":{"link":"https://www.link1.com"}},
    {"insert":" and here is "},
    {"insert":"link 2","attributes":{"link":"https://www.link2.com"}},
    {"insert":" and now finally "},
    {"insert":"link 3","attributes":{"link":"https://www.link3.com"}},
    {"insert":" cool."}
    ] */
```

This looks like what you want.  Of course there are all sorts of potential edge cases here so you should be very careful to specify exactly what you want to happen when you get "weird" input.  For example, the function does this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(parse({
    text: "What do you $expect$ to happen here",
    links: {
        " to happen here": ["oopsie", "doopsie"],
    }
})))
/* [
    {"insert":"What do you "},
    {"insert":"$expect$"},
    {"insert":"oopsie","attributes":{"link":"doopsie"}}
    ] */
```

Is that "correct"?  Who knows.  So be careful.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGSOUgA8wAuZAZzClAHMBuA45AG1AGtqrtkA2lyq16IBgF0qA0YwA0NOownIAPsgCuIACYQYoCNuQBfAqfwFQkWIhQAFOFGqH0mHK2KhnUSorHMPIgwlACMNSGoAfj4ObhElcRMzAgIEAHsQWmRtDDgqVywAXndCYjJfAHIACQh2djSSAAtgamQW5AASThAuAEYO5DgdZEboFHau7gAmAaGjEDSAd2R9EDg6gE9O7q4AZgH0tPYAOgq5QNie3hK2Nkme-ekKneRds+QKxrAwAAdeAHp-otgccdrtjukALYVCTnUq3bbcfpPF69d6fb5-CiA4GLUFIiFpaGwi53HYzFHcZBTdFfX4AoEg8mE4kXczGFgWLnpTJgZA-RzOZDFAAU2nyuQAlFQHE4XLkBCpCgA+bLHcrHC7UH6cMAi-4igA6HUNiwA1MbJf9JZr4chIXAfiLWirkCL+NdqAp2FRtPirjIVMZJTaLg6ne6aN6TJLhar2MhIjg2ploL52AIAAywwbfehhCIxHZUDO9IMmZAxLxpkQxzmpDLUI4QUFpBgigBSAGUAPIAOWOsnEwBgGxFArlYqlIc5-wAVIILtgAETVnzLijLmp1BpgZqtdrL4xwtgrtdgDfL1HLuTL4L58IQagblc7S90rE4pkEqFH49L1dU3XTdBmGUYoHGVojxPYgzyAi9NxeKYbzvPNgALJ8Xyvbh30xBlcX9LgphZP8YKIODvAQ5dQPmJYVlAdZ2C2aCAPPS8Xl2FD73Qx9nwoV8cM3D98O-B4SOMf87QotNL2QQ4TiPC4VDnf5WAbTJm1bdtu37QcEgYEcxwnZx3QucoqGXAB1RoMGyBoNjSDROggUgfggBAwAGMAGhsn43JAEYxhvC4dmuPA7TYajvJGR1-MCiCN0EZc0jSP5gAgG9kGXbQUrSjKSTtdkQ0lAh50XKTAMoy9rNsnLkAcpyWIqtjNw6Fy3I8jomtPSqZM3XLqHSri0IwviBJ6S8ctSwaMokpTkBUoA)

---

UPDATE: you asked how to go the other direction.  That's *really* a separate question but here's my answer:

```
function unparse(parsedData: ParsedData[]): Data {

    function uniqueLinkKey(links: { [k: string]: any }, displayString: string): string {
        const k = displayString.replace(/\W/g, "");
        let i: "" | number;
        for (i = ""; "$" + k + i + "$" in links; i = +i + 1) { }
        return "$" + k + String(i) + "$";
    }

    const ret: Required<Data> = { text: "", links: {} };
    for (let d of parsedData) {
        if (d.attributes) {
            const key = uniqueLinkKey(ret.links, d.insert);
            ret.text += key;
            ret.links[key] = [d.insert, d.attributes.link];
        } else {
            ret.text += d.insert;
        }
    }
    return ret;

}
```

This produces the following result when fed the output of the previous function:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(unparse(parsedData)));
/* { "text":"Hello this is $link1$ and here is $link2$ and now finally $link3$ cool.",
      "links":{
          "$link1$":["link 1","https://www.link1.com"],
          "$link2$":["link 2","https://www.link2.com"],
          "$link3$":["link 3","https://www.link3.com"]
}} */
```

The implementation above is more of an imperative style because the functional-only approach might be too dense.  The only "interesting" thing going on there is that you probably don't ever want to overwrite the link keys if they have the same display text, so the `uniqueLinkKey()` function makes sure it generates a new link key not already present inside the `links` object being built:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(unparse([
    { insert: "Repeats are bad: " },
    { insert: "ECHO", attributes: { link: "https://one.example.com" } },
    { insert: " and " },
    { insert: "ECHO", attributes: { link: "https://two.example.com" } },
    { insert: " and " },
    { insert: "ECHO", attributes: { link: "https://three.example.com" } },
    { insert: "!" },
])));
/* {"text":"Repeats are bad: $ECHO$ and $ECHO1$ and $ECHO2$!",
    "links":{
        "$ECHO$":["ECHO","https://one.example.com"],
         "$ECHO1$":["ECHO","https://two.example.com"],
         "$ECHO2$":["ECHO","https://three.example.com"]
}} */
```

All three of the links have the display text `"ECHO"`, but the function produces three distinct keys: `"$ECHO$"`, `"$ECHO1$"`, and `"$ECHO2$"`.

Now again, there may be all sorts of edge cases and you should consider them.  But I am almost certainly done here.  Good luck!

[Link to updated code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGSOUgA8wAuZAZzClAHMBuA45AG1AGtqB+K7MgDaXKrXogGAXSpDxjADQ06jKcgA+yAK4gAJhBigIu5AF8C5-AVCRYiFAAU4UasfSYcrYqFdRKyiWYvIgwVACMtSD4BDm4xFUkzC1YCBAB7EFpkXQw4KncsAF5PQmIyfwByAAkIdnY0kgALYGpkFuQAEk4QLgBGDuQ4PWRG6BR2ru4AJgGhkxA0gHdkQxA4OoBPTu6uAGYB9LT2ADoKhWDYnuoBC7ZJnv3ZCp3kXbPkCsawMAAHa4B6f6LYHHHa7Y7pAC2FSk51KbCI9z6HSeL1670+3z+FEBwMWoO4vQhaWhsNuxCRM1R3GQUwxX1+AKBIJ2U2JpIullMLCsvPSmTAyB+zlcyGKAApdPlcgBKKhOFxuXJCNSFAB82WO5WOF2oP04YHF-3FAB0OibFgBqM0y-4ynXw5CQuA-cWtdXIcWCa40JTsKi6AlXXjHORqUwy+0XZ2ur2+jhmGVijXsZC8HBtTLQfzsIQABlhg2+9AiURiOyoud64bMyBiPmzYkTPIIMB0CDAwAy2hAwsV4r7rl0BXlIqVmBVcrQuRKFzbIA7XZAPeAAEctBAADLcADSEA24p2PsEInigRkgxAW1MSl0LX1cA2AGUEgwz4wp-JEnhHWx+VkuDFbJ73YR8X0CY4oAgB8kCNE0AHV-gYJQACIUJlHkEWIdgIEFYAqDQjRkBALRITCaBMKwlY0igT1gCAtCmGQFCOhQ5BLWQQCOPojiWLY0BLh4Jj6OKS0eOQXok0ESwqOQKCwC0KBlz49jONU8DGHFYAk141jKKISwLn-QV5KoAAlCB12AKDdAAHgKDVikEcoCJQv1uGPUwzH06jaMPXDsmQNIYCFMdh1lEpZOAELJWOUIS0iCBqCk8ksOMzj9yAnQ1w3bcej3A95KDHhb2OBs-Aw1KESK8p2OKLh9x82SiqPER91VYRA3KsBSvi4BSyS4qpCa4gvNqUUf1ktgaogcg6s1bqRoMzkLnkxTl3klt8EM-B0sHccilC-sckwSrdoyagjggUE0gYcUACknwAeQAOWOL8GGig99vC06zv+AAqYQLmwFDupQigUJqOoGjAZpWnaFCbxBsGsz8CGULRNyUL6gbqAh0GdgxhlsVxFlCXZJHkcdUHwchy8TFGKC2laJG4TYWm0bADGXimbHccS-GKEJ7hiaxJk8WKtkoSp9niE53xufpuZiKWFZQHWdgtjZlG6cxmldn54t+sFgn9Z6MXGRxZl8TBSnTGpjnUcVjHkEOE4kYuNQAf+AhUguq6brux7Xve18vvFHR9oHMKCkjf6gcEFDygx6H6iadoJh2foGZGMYWe2aZZmGBZllWTWtiRfY3bSI5jjc8lzZ4AmqqIFjs9YighCbiTsZJiXyZ6IkZbJX8EXbouIe73m+-F63JdZSnR6m5iq876eDdnq2ydt7hwRHiwvJ9v3zsyQP6mD563o+iPo8mspZv8FD4MaDBsgaDY0i0TpZp+CAOwGGABor8fh-2XEzCADdtrxwIIDYGNNnbZgxi-N+ugP5f2Yo7eWiD0aQw6L-f+YBWJYKIArJBkNa5-GAJAhQONjZ4zNkTSGaC0hUMgQ7L2yBj58gDjhIOD0r5h0CBHKOY5xRCBBpmRWBELJ-wwK0ZwKAwhwClMxMwctSFSMbMxAAogAYSqE9NyRZwiC3LHEZi-drYZGurNOAkJ9TXRlrWEhGZuoEVzmxVxgh3G6IMUYpQAsywZgrJYuegIwCLDSMcOxDi+HOK8t4rRfgPEqy8RotxXMCL6MMcYoJSVzE9AIlYiJjQoK2NIPYxxlMXEZJ8Vk5iABCdJBApDxx5HA0GKdIayIgPIwYzNlGqI6Dkp6xcTAjP8TnFWkzDEzGaRkpuQt75YRYqM9eKFRlb1Jv8GxMTKlxKcSSFCy9ZJrKmRsrZtCSn-EidE2J1SR4ZPHrMp6Mwp6bP8dspkcNyn7KqfE45UhD5cN9vgIAA)

Comment: Thanks for that awesome quick answer however what if `text` does does not contain placeholders and `link` key does not exist in that case it will not work.

Comment: If `text` does not contain placeholders then you get an array of one entry; you can try it yourself.  I don't understand how the `link` key can "not exist".  Can you show me a specific example of what "will not work"?

Comment: `const data = {text: "this is text"}` this should convert into `[{insert: "this is text"}]` in your above example this case will not work

Comment: also if we need to do vice versa means to convert this`[{insert: "please click"}, insert: "here", attributes: {link: "www.google.com"}, insert: "to go"] to this {text: "please click $here$ to go ", links: {$here$: ["here", "www.google.com"]}}` how can we achieve this.

Comment: If you can get this question reopened I'd be more than happy to respond to your followup questions; the change for `{text: "this is text"}` is so small that I'm surprised you need to ask: make `links` an optional property of `Data` and change `d.links[s]` to `d.links?.[s]` or `d.links ? d.links[s] : undefined`.  As for the "vice versa" question that's more effort than I'm willing to put in for the comments section of a closed question.  Good luck!

Comment: I've updated the answer but this is likely the last update; if you want more attention on this you should probably create a new question (see [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer) or other Stack Overflow etiquette links).  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I wrote quickly. It assumes that the links appear in the string with alphabetical order. If they are not you need to sort them based on the first that appears in the string.

```js
const data = {
      text: 'Hello this is $link1$ and here is $link2$ and now finally $link3$ cool.',
      links: {
        $link3$: ['link 3', 'https://www.link3.com'],
        $link1$: ['link 1', 'https://www.link1.com'],
        $link2$: ['link 2', 'https://www.link2.com']
      }
};

const format = (data) => {
  let str = data.text;
  const result = [];
  Object.keys(data.links).sort().map((key) => {
    if (str.indexOf(key) > 0) {
      result.push({ insert: str.substring(0, str.indexOf(key)) })
    }
    result.push({
      insert: data.links[key][0],
      attributes: { link: data.links[key][1] }
    });
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf(key) + key.length)
  })
  if (str.length) {
    result.push({
      insert: str
    })
  }
  return result
}

console.log(format(data));
```